# Add a solo pseudo network card in docker

Tags: docker

The eth0 in docker could let me access the internet for update packages.
I require a eth1 which is unique ip for local network program testing.
So, I can assign all my network test program to eth1 to prevent output the network packets out.

Comment: Check out [pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework) - it allows you an incredible level of control over the networking of your containers.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `--net=host` you have access to all the interfaces on the network inside the container.

Comment: I don't want all the interface. I just want the original default behavior(NAT a internal ip). And an extra dummy interface eth1 for my network programs.